# Docker DNS Server not contactable outsid container

Tags: linux, docker, dns

I know this looks like a duplicate post, but I did review the others and even tried some options from those posts but nothing seemed to get it working.

I have a bind DNS Server running in a Docker container.

```
docker run --name=dns-server -it -d --dns=8.8.8.8 --dns=8.8.4.4 -p
53:53/tcp -p 53:53/udp -v /DATA/etc/bind:/etc/bind -v /DATA/var/cach
/bind:/var/cache/bind -v /DATA/var/log/named:/var/log/named jon/dns-server
```

Running fine:

```
[root@docker-01 ~]# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED         STATUS              PORTS                                    NAMES
8272ac164460        jon/dns-server      "/entrypoint.sh"    34 seconds ago      Up 34 seconds       0.0.0.0:53->53/tcp, 0.0.0.0:53->53/udp   dns-server
```

port 53 is exposed on both udp and tcp...

```
[root@docker-01 ~]# docker port dns-server
53/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:53
53/udp -> 0.0.0.0:53
```

If I do a lookup on the container address:

```
[root@docker-01 ~]# host google.com 172.17.0.2
Using domain server:
Name: 172.17.0.2
Address: 172.17.0.2#53
Aliases: 

google.com has address 216.58.206.78
google.com has IPv6 address 2a00:1450:4009:815::200e
google.com mail is handled by 20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx.l.google.com.
```

However, when I try with the host address:

```
[root@docker-01 ~]# host google.com 192.168.56.101
Using domain server:
Name: 192.168.56.101
Address: 192.168.56.101#53
Aliases: 

Host google.com not found: 5(REFUSED)
```

It gets refused.

I've tried adding rules into iptables to allow port 53 through, and I've also tried subsituting the published ports in docker run with `--net=host`

It feels like I'm close to getting this working but I think it's iptables which is throwing me off.

I don't think using the container address as the DNS Server is an option because ultimately I need to move this VM (the host) to an esxi host for it to serve DNS for other VM's in that environment.

Thanks
Jon

Comment: Have you seen this Github discussion -> https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-bind/issues/3

Comment: Thanks for that, I've had a read through and tried adding the forwarding in iptables between the docker interface and the public interface but still no joy :(